# Comparing sample covariance matrices to a model

Tags: hypothesis-testing, multivariate-analysis

I have several sample variance/covariance matrices, say $[C_1...C_n]$. These covariance matrices correspond to blocks of correlated multivariate normal samples (i.e. the samples used to estimate $C_1$ are not completely independent, but they are completely independent from the samples used to estimate $C_2$). In reality, there is a true variance/covariance matrix $C$; the $C_i$ should be samples from some distribution with expectation $C$. I also have two nested models that lead to predictions of this true variance/covariance matrix (say, $V_0$ and $V_1$).

I'm looking to test formally whether $V_1$ is a better fit to $[C_1...C_n]$ than $V_0$ (the model for $V_0$ is nested within $V_1$). I've looked for a standard way to do this, but can't seem to find anything (e.g. Wilks' lambda and other MANOVA-type tests don't seem to be exactly what I'm looking for).

Is there a way to write down a likelihood for $[C_1...C_n]$ given $V_0$ (or $V_1$)? Or some other way to compare the fit of these models?